# C++11 chained construction compliance in g++

Tags: c++, g++, c++11

I was just wondering if g++ actually complies with the C++11 standard of chained constructors (or whatever it's called).

example:

```
class MyClass
{
  MyClass(int x, int y = 0);
  MyClass(int y = 0) : MyClass(8, y) {}
};
```

I keep getting this error even though I've included the -std=c++0x (or -std=gnu++0x) parameter (there is no -std=c++11)

> error: type ‘MyClass’ is not a direct base of ‘MyClass’

I don't want to jump to conclusions and I've looked around the net but can't seem to find any information about it.

By the way, I'm using g++ (Debian 4.6.2-4) 4.6.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's [not yet supported](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) (look for delegating constructors).

Other than that, don't you think your design is highly ambiguous? What should `MyClass(1)` call?

Comment: good catch on the ambiguity.  i was just making an example.  my real code uses two (very) different types, so i dont have that problem.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417314/c-init-member-variables-with-multiple-constructors#comment13441709_10417381