# C++ init member variables with multiple constructors

Tags: c++

Usually a constructor should look like this:

```
//ctor1
SmallSim::SmallSim()
:mSimInit(false)
,mServersCreated(false)
,mTotalCPUTime(0)
{
    ...
}
```

What happens if I have multiple constructors?

It looks to me that If I call the first constructor from my second, the member vars in the first do not get initialized.

```
//ctor2
SmallSim::SmallSim(bool ImmediateExecution, bool Report)
{
    SmallSim();

    ...
}
```

So do I need to repeat 
    :mSimInit(false)
    ,mServersCreated(false)
    ,mTotalCPUTime(0)
on every constructor I have?

As far as I know using an InitClassVars() is not the best way to go...

```
//ctor1
SmallSim::SmallSim()
{
    InitClassVars();

    ...
}

//ctor2
SmallSim::SmallSim(bool ImmediateExecution, bool Report)
{
    InitClassVars();

    ...
}

//Common function for init of member vars for multiple constructors
void SmallSim::InitClassVars(void)
{
    mSimInit = false;
    mServersCreated = false;
    mTotalCPUTime = 0;
}
```

Is there a correct way to Init the member vars with out repeating the init on every constructor?

Comment: Are you using C++03 or C++11?

Comment: I'm coding with gcc -std=c++0x   so I'm thinking 11 since smart pointers work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you do this:

```
SmallSim::SmallSim(bool ImmediateExecution, bool Report)
{
    SmallSim(); // 1

    ...
}
```

The line marked with 1 creates a new `SmallSim` temporary object which is readily destroyed since it is not used. It has no effect whatsoever on the object currently being initialized. To call another constructor on the same object you do it like this:

```
SmallSim::SmallSim(bool ImmediateExecution, bool Report)
: SmallSim() {
    ...
}
```

(This is a C++11 feature.)

Comment: Examples are always helpful, thanks, accept now i'm getting an error saying "type 'SmallSim' is not a direct base of 'SmallSim'" any ideas? my C++11 flag is on...

Comment: @DieSlower probably your compiler doesn't support delegating constructors yet. AFAIK, you need at least GCC 4.7 or Clang 3.0.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes That's it! I'm on gcc 4.6  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There are two options in C++03:

- Use an init function which you call from every ctor
- Provide an initializer list for all ctors

In C++11 you can use delegating ctors so that you can call one ctor from all others.

Comment: You must be careful when adding an init called from every constructor. Make sure that this method is not virtual as calling virtual method inside the constructor does not always give the results you would expect.

Comment: @J_D: That is of course a given requirement, refer to FAQ 23.5 <http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.5> (though you can technically use virtuals, if you are *very*, *very* careful and under special conditions.)!

Comment: @J_D obviously you would only be initialising variables from that class, so I don't know why you'd be expecting a virtual function to work there.

Comment: The delegating ctors I think is the answer. But now i'm getting an error saying "type 'SmallSim' is not a direct base of 'SmallSim'" any ideas? My C++11 flag is on...

Answer (score 2):

There is no correct way to do it. If you delegate your initialization to a function, then you default initialize your data once and then assign values. If you want to benefit from initialization list construction, then you have to repeat yourself. Preferences vary.

Fortunately C++11 allows delegating constructors, see [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#delegating-ctor).

C++11 also allows initialization at the point of declaration, which may help:

```
struct Foo {
  int i{0};
  double x{0.}:
};
```

Here, constructors don't have to do anything about `i` or `x`, unless they want to change the values.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @juanchopanza, there is not "right" or "perfect" way of dealing with constructors, there are several ways to allocate an object, and initializate its fields / properties.

I don't recommend a constructor call another constructor, on the same class, it can a mess.

Sorry, I didn't understand well your example, I'll use a simple one. Lets suppouse there is this business hotel for traveling salesmen that has an automated restaurant.

There is some machines that take orders, some food is ready, such as coffe, bread or cake, juice, while other food like waffles, eggs ,take time to be prepared.

A customer can arrive to the restaurant go to the machine, and press some buttons with its order. He (she) may request to be served some of the already prepared food, such as coffee, while waiting for other food. He may also take an empty plate, and wait, all to be served togheter.

He can return later, for more of anything, at the same price.

This example will define a class that represent the machine that take the orders.

Please ignore minor syntax, errors & bugs, and check this idea to dealing with constructors & initialization of fields.

---

```
// note: good idea to add an empty value to enumerations:

enum BeveragesEnum {
  none,
  water,
  orangejuice,
  milk,
  coffe,
  cocoa
}; // enum BeveragesEnum

enum BreadsEnum {
  none,
  donut,
  bagel,
  cherrypie,
  applepie,
  cake
}; // enum BreadsEnum

enum FoodEnum {
  none,
  ScrambledEggs,
  OverEggs,
  Chicken,
  Waffles,
  Pancakes,
  Beef
}; // enum FoodEnum

class AutomatedCafeteriaClass
  protected: 
    BeveragesEnum Beverage;
    BreadsEnum Bread;
    FoodEnum Food;

    public:
      /* constructor*/ AutomatedCafeteriaClass();
      /* destructor*/ ~AutomatedCafeteriaClass();

    public:
      void quickGiveMeCoffe();
      void wantCoffeAndBread
        (
          BreadsEnum aBread
        );
      void onlyBeverage(BeveragesEnum aBeverage);
      void BeverageBreadFirstFoodLater
        (
          BeveragesEnum aBeverage;
          BreadsEnum aBread;
          FoodEnum aFood;
        );
      void waitForEverything
        (
          BeveragesEnum aBeverage;
          BreadsEnum aBread;
          FoodEnum aFood;
        );
      void wantFood
        (
          FoodEnum aFood;
        );

    public:
      void prepare();
}; // class AutomatedCafeteriaClass

/* constructor*/ AutomatedCafeteriaClass::AutomatedCafeteriaClass()
{
  // first assign empty values
  this.Beverage = BeveragesEnum.none;
  this.Bread    = BreadsEnum.none;
  this.Food     = FoodsEnum.none;
} // constructor AutomatedCafeteriaClass

/* destructor*/ AutomatedCafeteriaClass::~AutomatedCafeteriaClass()
{
  // clear by assigning empty values
  this.Beverage = BeveragesEnum.none;
  this.Bread    = BreadsEnum.none;
  this.Food     = FoodsEnum.none;
} // constructor AutomatedCafeteriaClass

void AutomatedCafeteriaClass::quickGiveMeCoffe()
{
  this.Beverage = BeveragesEnum.Coffe;
  prepare();
}

void AutomatedCafeteriaClass::wantCoffeAndBread
(
BreadsEnum aBread
)
{
  this.Beverage = BeveragesEnum.Coffe;
  this.Bread    = aBread;
  prepare();
}

void AutomatedCafeteriaClass::onlyBeverage(BeveragesEnum aBeverage)
{
  this.Beverage = aBeverage;
  prepare();
}

void AutomatedCafeteriaClass::BeverageBreadFirstFoodLater
(
BeveragesEnum aBeverage;
BreadsEnum aBread;
FoodEnum aFood;
)
{
  this.Beverage = aBeverage;
  this.Bread    = aBread;
  this.Food     = aFood;
  prepare();
}

void AutomatedCafeteriaClass::waitForEverything
(
  BeveragesEnum aBeverage;
  BreadsEnum aBread;
  FoodEnum aFood;
)
{
  this.Beverage = aBeverage;
  this.Bread    = aBread;
  this.Food     = aFood;
  prepare();
}

void AutomatedCafeteriaClass::wantFood
(
  FoodEnum aFood;
)
{
  this.Food     = aFood;
  prepare();
}

void AutomatedCafeteriaClass::prepare();
{
  // prepare the food
}
```

---

Note, that all those functions, altought, not constructors directly, initialiaze fields as a constructor does, also called "postconstructors" or "initialiazers".

Its also possible, to convert all these functions into real constructors, but, can be some a mess, so its easier, that each function, has its own identifier.

Cheers.